# Sidebar height isn't changing together with the content height

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

This is how the sidebar looks like at its' beginning stage: https://i.stack.imgur.com/epGgs.png

And there is no problem while the content fits the original page size: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sfxhb.png

But once the columns are place under one another, the sidebar height remains the same leaving empty space at the bottom: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5siM4.png

The sidebar is place inside the wrap:

```
#wrap {width: 100%; height: 100%; position: absolute; top: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 0}
.sidebar {width: 200px; height: 100%; float: left; background: #65A973; position: relative; bottom: 0px}
```

Some html

```
    <div id='wrap'>
        <div class='sideBar'>
           //something goes here 
        </div>
        <div id='content'>
           //something goes here 
        </div>
        <div class='clear'></div>
    </div>
```

Comment: please post minimum html code or jsfiddle

Comment: does this problem occurs when you get a scroll bar?

Comment: If so your height 100% is relative to body & to make it relative to content div you would have to use table-cell layout.

Comment: @ImranBughio, indeed! On all devices, including iphones 4 and 5, but not iPad or iphone6.

Comment: so it is relative to body right? means the sidebar height will be smaller on iPhone as compared to a bigger height device like iPad and Monitors ?

Comment: @ImranBughio the sidebar is relative to the #wrap. when you suggest to use table cell layout, what object shall act as a table cell?

Comment: Could you use `position:fixed;` in combination with `top:0;left:0;bottom:0;`? This would make sure it always stretches from top to bottom. Don't forget to apply a `margin-left:[normal margin + sidebar width];` to your actual contents on the right. Also note that this solution will disallow scrolling in the sidebar (but not on the rest of the page).

Comment: @FDekker, I guess I will stick to your solution as I have tried all other suggestions and fixed position seems to be the only one working.

Comment: @IvanMaestro I have added an answer with practically the same contents of the comment so that this question can be formally closed.

Comment: Although I suggest you to use the position fixed solution but here is a little code i wrote for table-cell solution http://jsfiddle.net/prma8kyz/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This to formalise my comment into an answer:

I suggest using `position:fixed;` for the following CSS for the sidebar:

```
#sidebar {
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    width:[some width];
}
```

Now make sure to increase the margin for the rest of your contents so that they don't disappear behind the sidebar:

```
#contents {
    margin-left:[sidebar width + normal margin];
}
```

Do note that you can no longer scroll inside the sidebar now, but scrolling on the rest of the page stays intact.

Answer (score 1):

Add these properties.

```
.sidebar{
  width: 200px;
  height: 100%;
  position:fixed;
  display:block;
  top: 0;
  }
```

Comment: This is actually quite a good idea. however do add an `overflow: auto;` and you might have to add custom scroll if the menu gets big.

Answer (score 0):

You want a column with 100% height expandable when right column is tall. You face this problem because your 100% height is referred to viewport and not real DIV height

You can achieve this only with `position:absolute` in left column (use a padded content to take correct alignment)

https://jsfiddle.net/2zes2ewL/